# grep or search for a string in a tuple - python

Tags: python, list, grep, tuples

I'm really new with python and I'm trying to figure it out how to do a grep from a tuple or list.

I have a result from a query like this:

```
[(123456, '123_ABC', 'abc123defa', '/path/whatever', 11111L, 'YES'),
(789456, '123_DEF', 'abc123defb', '/path/whatever/0', 11111H, 'NO'),
(234567, '123_GHI', 'abc123defc', '/path/whatever/1', 11111T, 'NO')]
```

The result of the query has multiple rows like the example above. The user enters a "grep" string something that he is looking for, lets say "789456" so the result should print only:

`789456, '123_DEF', 'abc123defb', '/path/whatever/0', 11111H, 'NO'`

Perhaps, plane text without quotations and separated by "|" (I don't know really I can deal with that thing later).

So my question is, should I changed to tuple to a list first and then try create a function to do the "grep"? Is the same if I leave it as a tuple and I do the "grep" from there? I was looking for something without looping trough the data.

Comment: yes, it's the same if you leave it as a tuple

Comment: Does the search need to search all values in each row or just the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep rows that have `789456` with a list comprehension:

```
queries = [(123456, '123_ABC', 'abc123defa', '/path/whatever', '11111L', 'YES'),
          (789456, '123_DEF', 'abc123defb', '/path/whatever/0', '11111H', 'NO'),
          (234567, '123_GHI', 'abc123defc', '/path/whatever/1', '11111T', 'NO')]

to_keep = 789456

print([query for query in queries if to_keep in query])
# [(789456, '123_DEF', 'abc123defb', '/path/whatever/0', '11111H', 'NO')]
```

Or with [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter):

```
list(filter(lambda x: to_keep in x, queries))
```

Comment: what if I want to define 789456 as a variable on that line? print([query for query in queries if "VARIABLE" in query])

Comment: @vanboxen I added the variable `to_keep` in the code above.

Comment: yes, I did the same in my code with a variable set by the user but it looks like when I run the code the variable is empty. I will have to figure it out. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @vanboxen No problem. Good luck :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` to check if value is in tuple.

**Ex:**

```
d = [(123456, '123_ABC', 'abc123defa', '/path/whatever', 11111, 'YES'),(789456, '123_DEF', 'abc123defb', '/path/whatever/0', 11111, 'NO'),(234567, '123_GHI', 'abc123defc', '/path/whatever/1', 11111, 'NO')]

for i in d:
    if 789456 in i:
        print i
```

**Output:**

```
(789456, '123_DEF', 'abc123defb', '/path/whatever/0', 11111, 'NO')
```

Comment: That should work but I forgot to mention that I prefer to not loop through the data. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can do it without a loop.

Comment: @vanboxen how would you go through all elements without looping?

Comment: Actually, yes... looping should be answer. Thanks guys.